# StoredProc datatype for list of Id's

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

What should I define my datatype as in the StoredProc below if I want to pass a list/string of IDs eg. (1, 2, 5, 12, 99)?

```
create PROCEDURE [dbo].[TABLE_Delete]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @TId datatype = null
AS
BEGIN 
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    delete from dbo.TABLE T where T.Id in (@TId)

END
```

My TId field is of type Int

Comment: What are you calling the sp from?

Comment: For a Java application

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass your data as a `nvarchar(xx)` for example as '1,2,3,4'
then use the split function to split them and write your query as

```
 delete from dbo.TABLE T where T.Id in (dbo.split(@param,','))
```

Here is the code of Split function

```
CREATE FUNCTION Split
(
  @delimited nvarchar(max),
  @delimiter nvarchar(100)
) RETURNS @t TABLE
(
-- Id column can be commented out, not required for sql splitting string
  id int identity(1,1), -- I use this column for numbering splitted parts
  val nvarchar(max)
)
AS
BEGIN
  declare @xml xml
  set @xml = N'<root><r>' + replace(@delimited,@delimiter,'</r><r>') + '</r></root>'

  insert into @t(val)
  select
    r.value('.','varchar(max)') as item
  from @xml.nodes('//root/r') as records(r)

  RETURN
END
GO
```

Comment: I am sorry to say that I am not following what you have written here. :(

Answer (score 0):

Another way to split

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnSplitString] 
( 
    @string NVARCHAR(MAX), 
    @delimiter CHAR(1) 
) 
RETURNS @output TABLE(splitdata NVARCHAR(MAX) 
) 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @start INT, @end INT 
    SELECT @start = 1, @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string) 
    WHILE @start < LEN(@string) + 1 BEGIN 
        IF @end = 0  
            SET @end = LEN(@string) + 1

        INSERT INTO @output (splitdata)  
        VALUES(SUBSTRING(@string, @start, @end - @start)) 
        SET @start = @end + 1 
        SET @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string, @start)

    END 
    RETURN 
END
```